# How to redirect the home page to a custom page?

Tags: customization

I had a WordPress site which was moved to a directory  called "test". Now, all the urls for the wordpress site is domain.com/test, /test/wp-admin. The main index page is a custom html page for domain.com. Now, I want to move the WP back to the root directory but let the domain.com point to the same custom html page. How can I achieve this? The custom html page is independent of the theme used in the WP site.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Put the code from the `index.html` page into a file called `front-page.php` and put that in your theme directory.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`wp_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect)

```
 <?php wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.com/your-page/', 301 ); exit; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing you can do is make it a anyname.php and wrap this tagline in it.

```
<?php Template Name: Index ?>

<html>elements within it</html>
```

In WordPress go to any page you create and choose template name: Index.

From WordPress go to Settings > Reading and choose the custom page you want. This will avoid bad seo practises and keep you using your html page dynamically.